# PostgreSQL - How to concatenate row values after a conditional

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a table in postgres:

```
| PersonID |Description | Value |
|----------|-------------|-------|
|     1    | Name        | Jane  |
|     1    | Last name   | Doe   |
|     1    | Age         | 23    |
|     1    | Country     | USA   |
|     2    | Name        | Steve |
|     2    | Last name   | Jobs  |
|     2    | Age         | 40    |
|     2    | Country     | India |
|     1    | Height      | 1.80  |
|     1    | Weight      | 80    |
|     2    | Height      | 1.72  |
|     2    | Weight      | 79    |
```

and I want this (obs: Ref code = height+weight):

```
| Name    | Last_name | Age | Country | Ref. code |
|---------|-----------|-----|---------|-----------|
| Jane    | Doe       | 23  | USA     | 1.8080    |
| Steve   | Jobs      | 40  | India   | 1.7279    |
```

I already has this script, but I don't have the concat part for the ref code column:

```
select person_id,
    max(case when description = 'Name' then value end) as name,
    max(case when description = 'Last name' then value end) as last_name,
    max(case when description = 'Age' then value end) as age,
    max(case when description = 'Country' then value end) as country
from mytable
group by person_id
```

Please help! And thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to concatenate those columns with double pipe characters such as

```
select q.*,
       name||last_name||country as "Ref. code"
  from
  (
   select person_id,
          max(case when description = 'Name' then value end) as name,
          max(case when description = 'Last name' then value end) as last_name,
          max(case when description = 'Age' then value end) as age,
          max(case when description = 'Country' then value end) as country
     from mytable
    group by person_id
  ) q
```

**Update :** In your current case, you can apply `string_agg()` function  to the single `value` column with conditional(whenever `description`s are either `Height` or `Weight`) such as

```
select person_id,
       max(case when description = 'Name' then value end) as name,
       max(case when description = 'Last name' then value end) as last_name,
       max(case when description = 'Age' then value end) as age,
       max(case when description = 'Country' then value end) as country,
       string_agg(case when Description in ('Height','Weight') then value end,'') as "Ref. code"
  from mytable
 group by person_id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=fce49374776d100b0944f0e94bc995ed)</kbd>

Comment: But what if in the ref. code we need other values that are not those that we selected (name, last_name, age and country)? Let's say they are height and weight, and we don't want to select them as columns

Comment: but your question doesn't tell what you explained within the comment @FranciscoEnriqueGiménezVera . Please update the question with detailed sample and information after pressing the **edit** button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string aggregation. Also, in Postgrs, we can simplify the aggregate expressions with `filter()`:

```
select person_id,
    max(value) filter(where description = 'Name'     ) as name,
    max(value) filter(where description = 'Last name') as last_name,
    max(value) filter(where description = 'Age'      ) as age,
    max(value) filter(where description = 'Country'  ) as age,
    string_agg(value, '-' order by description) filter(where description in ('Name', 'Last name', 'Country')) as ref_code
from mytable
group by person_id
```

This gives you the flexibility of adding any description that you like to the ref code, even if it is not returned by the other aggregate functions.

I would recommend adding a separator between the ref parts, so it is clearer how it is composed. I used `'-'` (you can change that to `''` if you don't want a separator).

Note that this orders values by their description. If you really want to fine-tune the ordering, then you can use a  `case` expression in the order by clause of the aggregation function:

```
string_agg(
    value, 
    '-' 
    order by case description
        when 'Name'      then 1
        when 'Last name' then 2
        when, 'Country'  then 3
    end
) filter(where description in ('Name', 'Last name', 'Country')) as ref_code
```